# coldfusion cfsearch is not working for keyword smoking

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfsearch, cfindex

I have Four files[One .PDF, one .doc and Two .docx]. I have created one ColdFusion collections named **"testCollection"** using ColdFusion Administrator. In Manage ColdFusion Collection screen i entered File Extensions [.pdf, .doc, .docx] and the directory path where the all 4 files are placed. Also checked the checkbox [Recursively Index Sub Directories]. Once i click submit i can see 5 documents with their size in Solr Collections.

After that i wrote below one cfm file to search file on the basis of their content.
**Search.cfm**

```
<cfcollection action="list" name="AllSolrCollections" engine="solr">
    <!--- Filter to the collection that this application uses. --->
     <cfquery name="chkSolrCollection" dbtype="query">
          select * from AllSolrCollections 
         where AllSolrCollections.name = 'testCollection'
      </cfquery>
    <cftry>
      <cfif chkSolrCollection.recordcount EQ 1>                 
          <cfsearch name="mySearch" collection="testcollection" criteria="Aged" startrow=1>
    </cfif>
  <cfcatch type="SearchEngine">
    <cfoutput>Error</cfoutput>                    
 </cfcatch>
 </cftry>
  <cfdump var="#mySearch#">
```

When i entered criteria "Aged" it is giving me the correct result and showing all files except one file **"Search_Not_Show_For_Aged.docx"** since it has no search criteria content "Aged".

My issue is When i entered criteria **"smoking"**, it is not giving me the correct result. it shows all files except one file **"Search_Not_Show_For_Smoking.docx"** but this files contains "smoking" word.
I put my files in dropbox and share [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wd8r4fyapyea2vs/AADzpXA__MYHZZQK7wTXQFVPa?dl=0)

Please suggest and help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we do optimize the collection, the searching will work. We can Optimize Collection using coldfusion administration or using coldfusion code.

To Optimize collection using coldfusion administration:

1. Login to /cfide/administartor/index.cfm
2. Data & Services > Coldfusion Collections
3. Click optimize icon in Actions section for each collection.